# Laravel Multiple Foreach on Controller

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, foreach

I have problem use Laravel I want to make a live search using ajax and I want to try foreach data on controller based on relation one to many but showing error like this

> "Property [proyek] does not exist on this collection instance."

This error because I'm trying to foreach relation one to many

> foreach($data->proyek as $row2)

This is My Controller

```
public function dtproyek(Request $request) {
    $data = Status::with('proyek')->orderBy('created_at','ASC')->get();

    foreach($data as $row)
    {
        $output .= '<li>'.$row->status.'</li>';

        foreach($data->proyek as $row2)
        {
            $output .= '<li>'.$row->proyek_name.'</li>';
        }

    }
    $data = array(
        'table_data'  => $output,
    );

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrong syntax use this

```
public function dtproyek(Request $request){
     $data = Status::with('proyek')->orderBy('created_at','ASC')->get(); //here is get that returns multiple collection 
        foreach($data as $row)
            {//here $row is the current $data's collection 
                $output .= '<li>'.$row->status.'</li>';

                foreach($row->proyek as $row2)
                    { //$row2 is collection of $row->proyek 
                        $output .= '<li>'.$row2->proyek_name.'</li>';
                    }

            }
            $data = array(
                'table_data'  => $output,
                );

            echo json_encode($data);
         }
}
```

Comment: please explain the changes you have made, that would be more helpful for OP

Comment: in the inner foreach you should use

 `$row2` instead of `$row`

Comment: nice
Thanks You